# зависимости maven

Tags: maven, импорт, dependency-injection, scope

в pom проекта определено следущее

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.bxt.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>list-bom</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</virsion>
       <type>pom</type>
       <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

в pom list-bom зопределена зависимость

```
 <dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
       <scope>${scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

при этом при сборке пректа появляется ошибка

> org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar is missing @... [unknown-version]

С другими библиотеками определенными таким же образом проблем не возникает. В чем может быть ошибка?